# Show html file containing arabic characters in webview android studio

Tags: html, android-studio, webview, arabic

I have a webview which loads a html file. The file contains arabic letters and html tags such as span tags. If i open the html file using a browser such as firefox, every thing is ok and characters are shown correctly. However, in the webview the arabic characters positioned inside the tags such as the span tag are shown separated from the characters positioned out of the tag. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: please post some efforts u have done so far

Answer (score 1):

At first i used unicode characters in the html file. But it was not the solution. Finally i found a solution. Maybe this is not the best solution, but it works for me. I added the join character in the html file programmatically. In other words,  before and after the text positioned in the span tag, i added the character.tostring((char)0x200D). This character  joins arabic characters positioned inside and outside the tags together and webview shows the correct result.